# eloquent passing all IDs to scope, not the current one

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have 2 loops in my view:

```
        @foreach($products as $product)

           ...

                @foreach($product->pricesOrder() as $price)

                ...

                @endforeach

           ...

        @endforeach
```

and the pricesOrder() scope in my Product model is as below:

```
public function scopePricesOrder($query)
{
    $product = $query->first();

    $prices = Price::join('sites as site', 'site.id', '=', 'prices.site_id')
   ->orderBy('site.order', 'asc')
   ->select('prices.*')
   ->where('product_id', $product->id)
   ->get();
}
```

the issue I'm having is the query that's getting passed to the scope is ALL the products, not a single product.

Or at least I think that's whats happening, for the result form the loops is all rows output are exactly the same, that is the content of the very first one, meaning the scope is always being sent the same productID. Even though each product ID is difference and not repeated.

I had assumed that because pricesOrder() is called on $product that it will only bet getting the query for that single product. Not all of them.

Running `dd($product);` in the scope will return all products, not the current one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scopes are supposed to make your query code readable and flexible, not necesserily to return some related data. So don't use scope here, but go with your 'simple method' or instead create relationship:

```
// Product model
public function pricesOrdered($direction = 'asc')
{
   $direction = ($direction == 'desc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';

   return $this->hasMany('Price')
     ->join('sites', 'sites.id', '=', 'prices.site_id')
     ->select('prices.*')
     ->orderBy('sites.order', $direction);
}
```

Then you can use it like any relation:

```
foreach ($product->pricesOrdered as $price)

// and reverse the order if necessery
foreach ($product->pricesOrdered('desc')->get() as $price)
```

Answer (score 1):

remove scope, use normal method in Product.php model

```
public function pricesOrder()
{
    $prices = Price::join('sites as site', 'site.id', '=', 'prices.site_id')
       ->orderBy('site.order', 'asc')
       ->select('prices.*')
       ->where('product_id', $this->id)
       ->get();

    return $prices;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that there are multiple ways to achieve your goal.

1: Make it a static function and pass product id as the parameter and get the query result using `Product::scopePricesOrder($product_id)`:

```
`public static function scopePricesOrder($product_id)
{
    $prices = Price::join('sites as site', 'site.id', '=', 'prices.site_id')
   ->orderBy('site.order', 'asc')
   ->select('prices.*')
   ->where('product_id', $product_id)
   ->get();
}`
```

2: Simply pass product id to scope function and get the query result using `$product->priceOrder()`

```
`public function scopePricesOrder($query, $product_id)
{
    $prices = Price::join('sites as site', 'site.id', '=', 'prices.site_id')
   ->orderBy('site.order', 'asc')
   ->select('prices.*')
   ->where('product_id', $product_id)
   ->get();
}`
```

3: If you simply want to use the current product id, Ezra's answer works fine.

Comment: You do realise that was the OP answering his own question, right? :)

Comment: lol. I did not notice that...I was working on other things while answering his question...